# Positioning SKShapeNodes on top of each other for graphical effects

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have an arbitrary shaped non-self-intersecting polygon SKShapeNode A. As a graphical effect I would like to position another SKShapeNode B with scale of 0.7 on top of A.

I'm lost in Sprite-Kits coordinate system. I cannot get the SKShapeNode B to position correctly. It should be a simple problem but I'm stuck with it. ALL HELP APPRECIATED!

```
                    createdShape.name = "whiteArea"
                    createdShape.strokeColor = shapeBorderColor
                    createdShape.lineWidth = 0.0
                    createdShape.fillColor = shapeFillColor
                    createdShape.alpha = 1.0
                    createdShape.zPosition = shapeZPosition
                    createdShape.glowWidth = 3.0

                    let graphicAddonShape = createdShape.copy() as! SKShapeNode 
                    graphicAddonShape.setScale(0.7)
                    graphicAddonShape.lineWidth = 0
                    graphicAddonShape.zPosition = shapeZPosition + 1
                    graphicAddonShape.fillColor = UIColor(red:  15/255, green: 15/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1.0)
                    graphicAddonShape.name = "blackArea"
                    graphicAddonShape.physicsBody = nil

                    graphicAddonShape.position.x = createdShape.frame.width/2 - graphicAddonShape.frame.width/2
                    graphicAddonShape.position.y = createdShape.frame.height/2 - graphicAddonShape.frame.height/2
                    createdShape.addChild(graphicAddonShape)
                    self.addChild(createdShape)
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler, if you could provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code which can produce the issue you are talking about. Also, as an addition you should add a picture which illustrates a desired output.

Comment: Some things to keep in mind aside from what @SteveIves already pointed, is that `frame` property ignores the children of that node. If you want children included in calculation, you should use  `calculateAccumulatedFrame()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete Xcode playground using your code plus I've added some code at the top to create the scene and to set some variables for the stroke and fill colour etc.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground

let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 320))

let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 320))

sceneView.presentScene(scene)

XCPShowView("My Scene", view: sceneView)

var createdShape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 35)
let shapeBorderColor = SKColor.greenColor()
let shapeFillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
let shapeZPosition: CGFloat = 1.0
scene.backgroundColor = SKColor.grayColor()

createdShape.name = "whiteArea"
createdShape.strokeColor = shapeBorderColor
createdShape.lineWidth = 0.0
createdShape.fillColor = shapeFillColor
createdShape.alpha = 1.0
createdShape.zPosition = shapeZPosition
createdShape.glowWidth = 3.0

createdShape.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150)

let graphicAddonShape = createdShape.copy() as! SKShapeNode
graphicAddonShape.setScale(0.7)
graphicAddonShape.lineWidth = 0
graphicAddonShape.zPosition = shapeZPosition + 1
graphicAddonShape.fillColor = UIColor(red:  15/255, green: 15/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1.0)
graphicAddonShape.name = "blackArea"

graphicAddonShape.position = CGPointZero // This will be in it's parent co-ordinate system
createdShape.addChild(graphicAddonShape)
scene.addChild(createdShape)
```

To see the output, you'll have to go to View->Assistant Editor->Show Assistane Editor.

You'll see that I set the `position` of graphicAddonShape to CGPoint(0,0). the `position` property of an SKShapeNode refers to it's centre so we're putting the centre of `graphicAddonShape` at position (0,0) in it's parent's (`createdShape`) co-ordinate system i.e. `createdShape`'s centre. To see the difference, change the 2nd from last line from:

```
createdShape.addChild(graphicAddonShape)
```

to

```
scene.addChild(graphicAddonShape)
```

to see how the black circle is positioned depending upon who it's parent is.

Comment: There is no size -attribute in SKShapeNode. Do you mean frame?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The results is as follows. Node A in white and Node B in black. Nodes aren't lining up and the difference between nodes is growning depending on which border they're near. http://d.pr/i/119rF

Comment: OK - SKShapeNodes don't have anchor points, and when positioning a child node (which is done in the parent's coordinate system), 0,0 is the centre. I've updated my answer with a complete Xcode playground that shows the 2 nodes on top of each other with graphicAddonShape centered on createdShape.